# How java-script is handles when new keyword is used with return function?

Tags: javascript

In java-script, I have a function that will return an object as below(General target is to use it to create new object):

```
function Info() 
{ 
    return {x: 0, y: 0 } 
}
```

Now I have no idea how java-script is handling the below two statements:

```
var objInfo1 = new Info(); /* I know this doesn't make sense but still works */
var objInfo2 = Info();
```

And also I do know that when using new keyword you should follow this syntax

```
function Info() 
{ 
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}
```

Both above statements gives same result, same type.

**Now here does java-script is ignoring the new keyword or it is creating 2 objects one because of new and one because of return?**

*Is there any performance impact?*

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the new keyword is somewhat flexible.

If you have a function which is returning an object, then having a `new` keyword or not really doesn't change anything:

```js
function A() {
  return { x: 1, y: 2 };
}

const a1 = new A();
const a2 = A();

console.log(a1);
console.log(a1 instanceof A);

console.log(a2);
console.log(a2 instanceof A);
```

If your function isn't returning an object directly, then you need the new keyword to create an instance of the object instead of just running the function:

```js
function A() { }

const a1 = new A();
const a2 = A();

console.log(a1);
console.log(a1 instanceof A);

console.log(a2);
console.log(a2 instanceof A);
```

There isn't really a performance hit.

In the case of a function that returns a new object, that is generally called a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). In JavaScript, it's just flexible.